# Is there a way to keep scipy savemat from squeezing my arrays?

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

The scipy savemat function appears to always squeeze my arrays (or perhaps matlab is doing it?) Example:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io as spio

x = np.zeros((10,10,10,1))
print(x.shape)
spio.savemat("x.mat", {'x': x})
```

Output:

```
(10, 10, 10, 1)
```

Then, in matlab:

```
load('x.mat')
size(x)
```

Output:

```
ans =

    10    10    10
```

Scipy's loadmat function has a `squeeze_me` kwarg, but savemat does not.

Comment: Look at the file with `loadmat` I eee the 4 dimensions.  Maybe it's MATLAB that''s removing the last dimension.  While that's the trailing inner most for `numpy`, its the outer most of MATLAB.  Can you add that extra dimension in MATLAB?

Comment: Good call, @hpaulj, I didn't think to look at loading it back into scipy. I guess it is matlab, then. The load() function has no squeeze argument that I see. I can't add the extra dimension in matlab because I'm handing data off to a colleague routinely and don't want them to have to do this manually.